# Meteor autoform method-update not working

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-helper

When using autoform with `type="method-update" meteormethod="someMethod"` the method will not actually get called.

The autoform I am having trouble with:

```
{{#autoForm id="archiveIssue" type="method-update" meteormethod="editIssue" collection="Collections.Issues" validation="keyup" doc=doc autosaveOnKeyup="true" resetOnSuccess="true"}}
  <fieldset>
    {{> afQuickField name="Archived.Archived_By" id="Archived.Archived_By" autocomplete="off"}}
    {{> afQuickField name="Archived.Archive_Notes" id="Archived.Archive_Notes" autocomplete="off" rows=5}}
      <div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#archiveIssue">Submit</button>
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
{{/autoForm}}
```

This is the method that I am trying to call (The PRINT never shows up in the in the server console):

```
editIssue: function(doc) {
  console.log("PRINT");
  Collections.Issues.update({
    "_id": doc._id
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "Archived.Archived": true,
      "Archived.Archived_By": doc.Archived_By,
      "Archived.Archive_Notes": doc.Archive_Notes
    }
  });
}
```

The 2 functions that should help get the doc:

```
  Template.archiveIssue.helpers({
    doc: function () {
      var tmp = Session.get("archiveDoc");
      return tmp;
    }
  });

  Template.archiveIssueModal.events({
    "click .archiveButton": function (event) {
      Session.set("archiveDoc", this);
      }
    });
```

Schemas

```
Schema.Archived = new SimpleSchema({
  Archived: {
    type: Boolean,
    optional: true
  },
  Archived_By: {
    type: String,
    optional: true
  },
  Archive_Notes: {
    type: String,
    max: 200,
    optional: true
  }
});

Schema.Issues = new SimpleSchema({
  Description: {
    type: String,
    max: 500,
    optional: true
  },
  Comments: {
    type: [Schema.Comments],
    max: 500,
    optional: true
  },
  User: {
    type: String,
    label: "User",
    optional: true
  },
  Archived: {
    type: Schema.Archived,
    optional: true
  },
});
```

Comment: Do you have a SimpleSchema attached to your Issues collection?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the post with the schemas in use.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you need an answer now. 
You need to define with Meteor.methods like this.

```
Meteor.methods({
  demoSubmission: function () {
```